# При удалении элемента DataGrid выдаёт исключение : "Операция недопустима, когда ItemsSource используется"

Tags: c#, wpf, oledb

Пишу тестовую программу для работы с БД Access, есть кнопка для удаления записи, но она не работает и выдаёт исключение, т.к. ItemSource уже используется для отображения таблицы, как исправить эту проблему? 
Отображение таблицы:

```
  private void BtnViewProduct_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Создание объекта подключения к базе данных
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Shemet1.mdb;");
        //Открытие соединения
        con.Open();
        //Создание объекта для получения данных из бд
        OleDbDataAdapter Adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from Товар", con);
        //Cоздание объекта для хранения данных
        DataSet DS = new DataSet();
        //Добавление данных через адаптер в экземпляр класса DataSet
        Adapter.Fill(DS, "Товар");
        //Отображение полученных данных
        datagrid1.ItemsSource = DS.Tables["Товар"].DefaultView;
        //Закрытие соединения
        con.Close();
    }
```

Удаление записи:

```
private void BtnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = datagrid1.SelectedIndex;
        datagrid1.Items.RemoveAt(index);
    }
```

Comment: `datagrid1.ItemsSource = DS.Tables["Товар"].DefaultView;` - тут вы грубо говоря привязали данные к контролу, то есть в этот момент он не копирует в себя элементы коллекции, а просто их отображает, не являясь при этом источником данных. И тут `datagrid1.Items.RemoveAt(index);` вы пытаетесь удалить из контрола (когда в нем нет элементов) что то. Удаляйте из источника данных, то есть из `DS.Tables["Товар"].DefaultView`.

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: "Операция недопустима, когда ItemsSource используется. Вместо этого получите доступ и измените элементы с помощью ItemsControl.ItemsSource." вот это исключение выдаётся, по этому как я понял там есть элементы, но как удалить напрямую, можно пример кода, я не совсем понимаю как к ниму обращаться

Comment: Перестаньте работать с контролом, даже думать о нем перестаньте, это не его ответственность хранить в себе элементы, особенно в WPF! Я вам уже сказал, что вам надо делать, удаляйте из `DS.Tables["Товар"].DefaultView` что надо. Я без понятия какие там методы есть, но наверно для удаления уж точно что то будет. Ну а вообще, лучше сделайте "модель", которая будет загружать данные в обычный `List<>` из базы и уже с этой моделью работайте.

Comment: В `DS.Tables["Товар"].DefaultView` есть метод для удаления, но как мне получить индекс выделенной строки чтобы его передать?

Comment: Вы же его уже получили, `int index = datagrid1.SelectedIndex;` нет?

Comment: К сожалению нет, но я уже решил проблему, спасибо за ответы